# Bypass proxy for datasource in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot 2.7.7 / Java8 application using two services: JMS and Oracle.
To be able to connect to the JMS queue, I need to connect to a proxy through socks, so I have set up the execution with:

`-DsocksProxyHost=socks.proxy -DsocksProxyPort=port`

The problem is the database host is not behind this proxy, I can connect to it disabling the socks properties in the command line. The database is configured with:

`spring.datasource.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/SRV_NAME`

Of course, in this case I cannot connect to the JMS queue.

Is there a way suitable in Spring (reliable and documented) so, having the socks active, I can bypass the proxy for the connection to the database?